# Why is different assembly code generated from a constexpr reference than a constexpr pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, code-generation, constexpr

I compiled the following program with MSVC `/O2` and clang:

```
int            i;
constexpr int& ir = i;
constexpr int* ip = &i;


int main()
{
    ir  = 1;
    *ip = 2;
}
```

```
MSVC /O2                           clang
===========================        =============================================
int i DD 01H DUP (?) ; i           i:
_DATA SEGMENT                              .long   0                       # 0x0
int & ir DQ FLAT:int i ; ir
_DATA ENDS                         ir:
                                           .quad   i
```

- Both compilers generate assembly code from `ir`, but not from `ip` (code from `main` is omitted above). See on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/oVKL3x). Why are `ir` and `ip` different? I learnt, that in assembly code references and pointers are the same.

Gcc does an even stranger thing. I compiled the following program with gcc `-O0` and `-O2`:

```
int            i;

constexpr int& ir1   = i;
constexpr int* ir1p1 = &i;

constexpr int& ir2   = i;
constexpr int* ir2p1 = &i;
constexpr int* ir2p2 = &i;

constexpr int& ir3   = i;
constexpr int* ir3p1 = &i;
constexpr int* ir3p2 = &i;
constexpr int* ir3p3 = &i;
```

```
gcc -O0            gcc -O2
=========          ==================
i:                 ir3:
  .zero 4                   .quad   i
ir1:               ir2:
  .quad i                   .quad   i
  .quad i          ir1:
ir2:                        .quad   i
  .quad i          i:
  .quad i                   .zero   4
  .quad i
ir3:
  .quad i
  .quad i
  .quad i
  .quad i
```

- With `-O0` why are there several `.quad i`'s under the reference variables?
- With `-O2` code is generated from references, but not from pointers. Why is this difference? See on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/euGepu).

Comment: Why do you expect the same code? Do you think pointers and references are the same thing?

Comment: @StephenM.Webb: I think, that there are similarities and differenses as well, but in assembly code I have never seen any difference between them. Thus the question arises: is the current difference necessary or just an oversight in the compler implementations?

Comment: Different compilers generate different code; News at 11. If there are multiple ways to generate code that leads to the same result, the C++ standard leaves it up to the implementation to pick one. You have *no* guarantees about what actual instructions will be generated, only that they will implement the behaviour the original source specified (unless there's undefined behaviour of course, then all bets are off).

Comment: That does look like a failure of the compilers to optimize to me. Probably because the constexpr reference doesn't really make sense and should be rather rare.

Comment: "With -O0 why are there several .quad i's under the reference variables?" - Maybe it makes things easier for the debugger? After all, that's the primary concern at `-O0`.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: The question was not about the different ways of code generation. Thanks for the nice explanation though. Well stated. How does several `.quad i`'s help the debugger?

Comment: @Dr.Gut I don't *know* whether it helps the debugger. I was just speculating. It could also be that it was the simplest thing for the compiler to generate and since you didn't enable the optimizer it wasn't cleaned up.

Comment: @Dr.Gut _"Both compilers generate assembly code from `ir`, but not from `ip`"_ -- I don't think this is true. It looks more like the compiler figured out that `ir` and `ip` can have the same assembly representation and so it optimized away `ip` as redundant. You're therefore left only with `ir`.

Comment: @cdhowie: Let's see a program with [only `ir`](https://godbolt.org/z/LCBPmp), and with [only `ip`](https://godbolt.org/z/YWxfjY). As you can see, code is generated from `ir`, but not from `ip`. So your theory does not explain our experience. In fact both of them can be optimized away, but `ir` is not. Why?

Comment: You’re being misled by the omitted directives in the Compiler Explorer output.  Some variables show up only as such.

Comment: @DavisHerring: I don't understand. Could you elaborate? How to use godbolt correctly? I don't want to be mislead again.

Comment: @Dr.Gut: There are several filter options (using the common funnel icon) that reduce the noise (nut unfortunately sometimes the signal) in the assembly output.  One of them is “directives”; try without it enabled.

Comment: @DavisHerring: Thank you. That answers one of three questions (Gcc: With `-O0` why are there several `.quad i`'s under the reference variables?) Someone please try the other two.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the directives issue, this is just **linkage**: `constexpr` implies `const` (on the variable itself, not its referent, if any), and thereby gives [internal linkage](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#internal_linkage) to your pointers.  (This is a hack to allow namespace-scope named constants in header files prior to C++17’s inline variables; it’s unfortunate that we have to remember it now.)  Since no other translation unit can refer to them, there’s no need to emit **symbols** for them; the references, however, can be declared and used elsewhere:

```
extern int &ir;
void count() {++ir;}
```

and so there must be a symbol to which to attach such uses.

Comment: `extern int& ir` does not link to `constexpr int& ir = i;`. I got unresolved external symbol. Therefore I think, the latter has internal linkage after all. It cannot be used in another translation unit.

Comment: @Dr.Gut: It [works for me](https://wandbox.org/permlink/wWmUB4Mlj1OkLbSC).

Comment: I am surprised, it worked with gcc. It didn't work with MSVC and clang. I don't understand, why.

Comment: Indeed it works. I forgot to add `def.cc` to the compilation, when I switched compilers. How can one create a link to a wandbox program?

Comment: @Dr.Gut: When you run it a Share link appears just above the output window.